# ListView in Fragment not showing up

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-activity, android-listfragment

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView) in a fragment, but when I run the app the SwipeMenuListView is not showing its contents, here on stack I found some guys using the listview inside the onCreateView method, I tried that but it didn't work

```
public class AutorizadasFragment extends Fragment {

    private SwipeMenuListView listView;
    private CustomArrayAdapter adapter;
    private List<String> data;

    public AutorizadasFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_autorizadas, container, false);


        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        data = new ArrayList<String>();

        data.add("Teste 1");
        data.add("Teste 2");
        data.add("Teste 3");
        data.add("Teste 4");
        data.add("Teste 5");

        listView = (SwipeMenuListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);

        adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(), data);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        SwipeMenuCreator creator = new SwipeMenuCreator() {

            @Override
            public void create(SwipeMenu menu) {
                // create "open" item
                SwipeMenuItem openItem = new SwipeMenuItem(
                        getActivity());
                // set item background
                openItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0xC9, 0xC9,
                        0xCE)));
                // set item width
                openItem.setWidth(90);
                // set item title
                openItem.setTitle("Open");
                // set item title fontsize
                openItem.setTitleSize(18);
                // set item title font color
                openItem.setTitleColor(Color.BLACK);
                // add to menu
                menu.addMenuItem(openItem);

                // create "delete" item
                SwipeMenuItem deleteItem = new SwipeMenuItem(
                        getActivity());
                // set item background
                deleteItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0xF9,
                        0x3F, 0x25)));
                // set item width
                deleteItem.setWidth(90);
                // set a icon
                deleteItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_exit);
                // add to menu
                menu.addMenuItem(deleteItem);
            }
        };

        listView.setMenuCreator(creator);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);


    }
}
```

XML:

```
 <LinearLayout
        style="@style/FormRegister"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is the xml you posted `fragment_autorizadas` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hold a reference to your root view by adding a private attribute
e.g.

```
private View rootView = null;
```

and change following line in onCreateView:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_autorizadas, container, false);
```

to

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_autorizadas, container, false);
```

Then you do not need to use "getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);"
(it would become "rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);")

I am proposing this because i am not sure the view created in onCreateView is actually added to your activities root view when onActivityCreated() is called.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be overridding `onViewCreated`. The view returned by `onCreateView` is passed to `onViewCreated`

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    listView = (SwipeMenuListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

}
```